# TWebBrowser.Navigate(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers) is not available in edgebrowser

Tags: delphi

Migration from Delphi XE8 to Delphi 11 is in progress.

In Delphi xe8, I used the post method using TWebBrowser.Navigate(URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData, Headers) .

However, in Delphi 11, I tried to call the post method through edgebrowser (or TWebBrowser's edge engine), but it was found to be impossible.

function TCustomEdgeBrowser.Navigate(const AUri: string)
=> Only the above functions exist

I'm looking for an answer on how to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "call the post method"? Please provide a more complete example of what you were able to achieve previously

Comment: i'm sorry. English translation was not good :-)

It means that used the post method in http request methods.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that you would need a component that supports the ICoreWebView2_2 and ICoreWebView2Environment2 interfaces and it seems that TWebBrowser and TEdgeBrowser don't support them.

Try using [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi) and run the [NavigateWithWebResourceRequestBrowser](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi/tree/main/demos/Delphi_VCL/NavigateWithWebResourceRequestBrowser) demo.

That demo shows how to navigate using a POST request with a TWVBrowserBase.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest call. Like this :

```
procedure TMainForm.GoBtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  TempRequest : ICoreWebView2WebResourceRequest;
  TempAdapter : IStream;
  TempParams, TempHeaders, TempMethod : string;
begin
  TempRequest := nil;
  TempAdapter := nil;

  try
    if assigned(FBody) then FreeAndNil(FBody);

    TempMethod  := 'POST';
    TempHeaders := 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    TempParams  := PostParam1NameEdt.Text + '=' + PostParam1ValueEdt.Text + '&' + PostParam2NameEdt.Text + '=' + PostParam2ValueEdt.Text;
    FBody       := TStringStream.Create(TempParams);
    TempAdapter := TStreamAdapter.Create(FBody, soReference);

    if WVBrowser1.CoreWebView2Environment.CreateWebResourceRequest(AddressCb.Text, TempMethod, TempAdapter, TempHeaders, TempRequest) then
      WVBrowser1.NavigateWithWebResourceRequest(TempRequest);
  finally
    TempRequest := nil;
    TempAdapter := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
It seems that Tedgebrowser does not support it yet.
I will try WebView4Delphi you answered.