# Migrating TWebBrowser code to TEdgeBrowser, how to send Post data?

Tags: delphi, twebbrowser, tedgebrowser

I am attempting to convert some code from `TWebBrowser` to use `TEdgeBrowser`, but I am having trouble figuring out how to send post and header data with an HTTP request.

Below is the `TWebBrowser` functionality that I'm trying to implement:

```
var
  VHeader, PostData: OleVariant;

PostData := VarArrayCreate([0, Length(XMLString) - 1], varByte) ;    
HeaderData := 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'+ '\n';

WebBrowser1.Navigate(StrUrl,EmptyParam,EmptyParam,PostData,VHeader);
```

How do I do the equivalent with `TEdgeBrowser`, or in `TWebBrowser` with `SelectedEngine := EdgeOnly`?

Comment: This question was answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72864306/twebbrowser-navigateurl-flags-targetframename-postdata-headers-is-not-avai/72865336#72865336